# Does this bubble sort variant already have a name?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

In my boredom today I decided to see if I could improve on a basic bubble sort without *(knowingly)* copying prior work. I know there have been many attempts to do so, and my approach seems closest to the [cocktail shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort), but that doesn't seem to quite match.

In the below code it scans forward, but as soon as a swap is necessitated, it scans backwards until it finds a sorted pair, then picks up where it left off to scanning forward.

Consider sorting an input array [1 4 2 0 8]:

1. [1 4] is sorted. No swap needed.
2. [4 2] is not sorted. Swap to [2 4]. Begin scanning backward.
3. [1 2] is sorted. Continue forward.
4. [4 0] is not sorted. Swap to [0 4]. Begin scanning backward.
5. [2 0] is not sorted. Swap to [0 2].
6. [1 0] is not sorted. Swap to [0 1]. Reach beginning of array. Continue forward.
7. [4 8] is sorted. No swap needed.
8. End of array.

```
1 4 2 0 8
1 4 2 0 8
1 2 4 0 8
1 2 0 4 8
1 0 2 4 8
0 1 2 4 8
```

```c
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void sort(int *arr, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);
            
            for (size_t j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--) {
                swap(&arr[j-1], &arr[j]);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Have I unwittingly copied something that didn't come up in my research, and if so, does it have a name?

Comment: Compare it to *insertion sort* with linear search for the point of insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is insertion sort.

In your implementation there are two places where `swap` is called. The first one is really a first case of the one that is in the loop. If you would change the loop variable of the outer loop so that it runs from 1 to `n-1` instead of 0 to `n-2` (same number of iterations), then this separate `swap` can be dropped, as it will be done in the first iteration of the inner loop:

```c
void sort(int *arr, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) { // i is one more than in your version
        for (size_t j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > arr[j]; j--) {
            swap(&arr[j-1], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And now compare this with the (first) pseudo code that Wikipedia gives for [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm):

> Pseudocode of the complete algorithm follows, where the arrays are zero-based:
>
> ```pascal
> i ← 1
> while i < length(A)
>     j ← i
>     while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
>         swap A[j] and A[j-1]
>         j ← j - 1
>     end while
>     i ← i + 1
> end while
> ```

It has exactly the same logic.

It is nice when you come to a certain algorithm by working it out for yourself before finding out it is actually an established algorithm. I bet you'll now never forget what insertion sort is.

You may want to read the rest of the Wikipedia article as it points out some improvements to this.